# Can we map a array to another array in C, like mapping a file?

Tags: c, memory-mapping

I have an array (1D), and other array of same size in **different** order (which will change according to the program situation) should also have the same value.

For example:

```
array1 = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

hence array2, should automatically have,

```
array2 = {4,2,3,1,5};
```

Some what you can say, i want to jumble up values according to my unique reference. But whenever parent array1 changes, array2 should also be updated at its respective indexes. Is it even possible? Array memory mapping? looping and saving to other array is taking time as this operation is iterated several times. I cannot do memcpy, because order can be different. Any pointers/helps/suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You mean `int *array2 = array1` ??

Comment: Nope. sequence will be different. As i had displayed in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no magical way to do this. What you need to do is store the actual values somewhere, and then access them through a [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) stored separately. Here's some example code that uses strings so the permutation and the values are clearly distinct:

```
char *strings[] = {"foo", "bar", "baz", "quux"};

size_t memory_order[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
size_t sorted_order[] = {1, 2, 0, 3};

// Get the k'th element in the memory order:
strings[memory_order[k]];

// Get the k'th element in the sorted order:
strings[sorted_order[k]];
```

Comment: Thanks. If my both arrays would have been in same order, then both of them can be mapped right? (i want to skip memcpy, i want to use mapping only)

Comment: @Vishwadeep: why would you do that? Just use two pointers that point to the same array.

Comment: Yes. Just want to learn memory mapping. Just looking on the capability of memory mapping.. Is it possible?

Comment: As you suggested in the example.. That is the exact way, how i had implemented.. I was looking for other possibilities..

Comment: @Vishwadeep: it's perfectly possible.

Comment: it completes my thirst. It is a request, can you suggest me some more links/sample/keywords to read more..

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, no. C doesn't specify a way to do that (which makes sense to me, since most computers don't either, and C tends to be fairly close to the metal).

The typical way to solve it is to manually do the re-mapping, of course:

```
static const size_t map1to2[] = { 3, 1, 2, 0, 4 };
```

Then do the accesses to `array2` through the remap:

```
printf("array2[3] is %d\n", array1[map1to2[3]]);
```

This maps the index `3` to `0`, and thus prints  `1`.

You can use macros to make it slightly more managable.

Comment: Ok. your suggestion Macro. But, looking on the computation side, load will be same? right?